# how to get sum of of records exist in each page in SSRS Report?

Tags: .net, reporting-services, sum, report, rdlc

i have ssrs report with 2 dataset  ,the report  contain tablix filled from dataset and data grouped by specific field in the dataset ,all i want is to get sum of specific column data exist in each page of the report  ( mean to sum records for each page individually )
Note :Page does not have fixed number of row in each Page and i don't want to be

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your dataset, and try to phrase more clearly what you want help with

Answer (score 0):

By generally, we aggregate the total in the group footer of tablix footer, you might also achieve this by doing so. In order to display the total sum in every page, we need to set the tablix footer repeated. Please refer to the steps below:

1. Select the Tablix in the report.
2. In the Groups pane, click the small triangle arrow at the top-right corner and select "Advanced Mode" to show static members.
3. In the Row Group hierarchy, select the (Static) item which corresponding to the group footer or tablix header in the table.
4. Specify the RepeatOnNewPage property to True, the KeepWithGroup property to Before, and the FixedData property to False.

After that, the total sum would repeated in every page.

In order to show the sum of data on every page, if there are groups in the tablix and the page break depends on the group, we can simply add a group footer, then specify the sum aggregation in it. However, if the page break only depends on the page size, we need to aggregate the sum for the current page in the page footer, please refer to the steps below:

1. Add Page Footer in the report.
2. Add a Textbox in the Page Footer.
3. Specify the expression in the Textbox like
   =Sum(ReportItems!TextboxName.Value) Please correct the Textbox name in the expression to the textbox in which the data field needs to be aggregated.
4. We can also add another Textbox to the PageFooter to refer to the totol sum in the tablix footer by the expression like
   =ReportItems!TextboxName.Value

Please also correct the Textbox name in the expression, and then hide the original tablix footer in the tablix.

show this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/38c1a7d3-f2db-4ed5-9287-34da112031ce/show-sum-total-on-every-page?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: So there are no options to add totals related solely to page in tablix but no to footer?